# Vue obfuscation best practices

Tags: vue.js, obfuscation

Hello there dev community.
I´m trying to obfuscate a Vue app using (https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/webpack-obfuscator) webpack-obfuscator

## vue.config.js

```
configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new JavaScriptObfuscator({})
    ],
```

but the chrome console output show lot´s of erros and the app becomes broken (simply doesn´t even show the landing page)

[image]

I´ve tried also (https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/obfuscator-loader) with the following build config ->

## vue.config.js

```
const obfuscatorOptions = {
  compact: true,
  controlFlowFlattening: false,
  controlFlowFlatteningThreshold: 0.75,
  deadCodeInjection: true,
  deadCodeInjectionThreshold: 0.4,
  debugProtection: true,
  debugProtectionInterval: true,
  disableConsoleOutput: true,
  domainLock: [],
  identifierNamesGenerator: 'hexadecimal',
  identifiersPrefix: '',
  inputFileName: '',
  log: false,
  renameGlobals: true,
  reservedNames: [],
  reservedStrings: [],
  rotateStringArray: true,
  seed: 0,
  selfDefending: true,
  sourceMap: false,
  sourceMapBaseUrl: '',
  sourceMapFileName: '',
  sourceMapMode: 'separate',
  stringArray: true,
  stringArrayEncoding: true,
  stringArrayThreshold: 0.75,
  target: 'browser',
  transformObjectKeys: true,
  unicodeEscapeSequence: false
}

module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, "./src") ],
          enforce: 'post',
          use: { loader: 'obfuscator-loader', options: obfuscatorOptions }
        },
      ]
    }
```

but the console prints the following errors

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/obfuscator-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot apply @injectable decorator multiple times.
    at E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\inversify\lib\annotation\injectable.js:8:19
    at DecorateConstructor (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.ts:1202:35)
    at Object.decorate (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.ts:742:24)
    at _decorate (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\inversify\lib\annotation\decorator_utils.js:42:13)
    at Object.decorate (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\inversify\lib\annotation\decorator_utils.js:55:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\event-emitters\ObfuscationEventEmitter.ts:7:9)
    at r (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\webpack\bootstrap:22:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\container\InversifyContainerFacade.ts:30:1)
    at r (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\webpack\bootstrap:22:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\src\JavaScriptObfuscatorFacade.ts:11:1)
    at r (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\webpack\bootstrap:22:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\index.ts:3:1)
    at r (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\webpack\bootstrap:22:1)
    at E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\webpack\bootstrap:74:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\downloads\whats-app-sender-dashboard\coreui-free-vue-admin-template-master\node_modules\javascript-obfuscator\dist\webpack:\JavaScriptObfuscator\webpack\bootstrap:74:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:1:7)
    at Object../src/main.js (http://127.0.0.1:8080/app.js:1197:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://127.0.0.1:8080/app.js:724:30)
    at fn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/app.js:101:20)
    at Object.1 (http://127.0.0.1:8080/app.js:1211:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://127.0.0.1:8080/app.js:724:30)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/app.js:791:37
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/app.js:794:10
```

[image]
So, how to obfuscate sucessfully a vue app?

Comment: *but the console prints even more errors* - what errors? The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clear problem statement. Posting a workable example that can be debugged may help to get an answer.

Comment: Best practice: Don't. Basic minification already handles a casual attacker. Obfuscation won't stop a determined one. Nothing in your client-side code should be secret.

Comment: @EstusFlask... I´m editing the question right now and I´m inserting these errors... if you want to take a look... it will be available

Comment: @ceejayoz... so how about you please point some vue app minification best practices... thanks in advance...

Comment: @AdrielWerlich All the default Vue CLI templates come with minification built in. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html.

Comment: @ceejayoz... if I simply put ```module.exports = {
  mode: 'production'
}``` that´s is enough to make it minified? I mean, in webpack 4?!

Comment: I can't speak to your particular setup, only what the official Vue templates provide.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

I´m currently using the following setup in order to achieve the desired result of uglifying the js code from the build process of vue apps using TerserPlugin

## vue.config.js file

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
```

[image]

The result is resonably well obfuscated code:

[image]

However it´s still possible to see the options of the Vue app instance